# 3 informations from FORM ; need a creation and unicity between table (php code) msql query

Tags: php, mysql

Actually i got 3 informations receive by a user from FORM, for instance :

```
Aircraft :::::::::::            Part::::::::::::          Project :

 1. A380.......                      1.ATA 20....                   1.June 2015
 2. B787.......                      2.ATA 21....                   2.July 2016
 3. MRJ........                      3.ATA 22....                   3.April 2017
 4. ................                 4. ..............                     4. .....
etc .....
```

---

What I want to do is every time a user enter 3 informations, to create a single unique table where I 'll able to put some information. At the beginning my tables are empty. Would like to create each time a unique table, for instance a table whit column B787 ATA 36 AUGUST2017 and the unability to create twice the same table

I know I need to do white primary key, unique ID, some stuff like that but I am actually lost if someone could help me whit the PHP code that can do that kind of things I would appreciate it.

Hope you could understand what I am trying to explain :)

This is my code right now, but this code just create line in a new table , but is not creating single table every time actually :

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {//Check it is comming from a form

    //mysql credentials
    $mysql_host = "localhost";
    $mysql_username = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    $mysql_database = "bdd2";

    $u_aircraft = filter_var($_POST["Aircraft"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //set PHP variables like this so we can use them anywhere in code below
    $u_part = filter_var($_POST["Systeme"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $u_project = filter_var($_POST["Projet"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if (empty($u_aircraft)){
        die("Please enter an aircraft");
    }
    if (empty($u_part)){
        die("Please enter valid part");
    }

    if (empty($u_project)){
        die("Please enter a project");
    }   

    //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
    $mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

    //Output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }   

    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO presentation (aircraft, part, project) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"); //prepare sql insert query
    //bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
    $statement->bind_param('sss', $u_aircraft, $u_part, $u_project); //bind values and execute insert query

    if($statement->execute()){
        print "OK " . $u_aircraft . " as été ajouté avec succés à la Base de donnée";
    }else{
        print $mysqli->error; //show mysql error if any
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you are creating each time a unique table what ?

Comment: why do you want to create table each time?

Comment: Yeah, would like to create each time a unique table, for instance a table whit column            B787    ATA 36     AUGUST2017              and the unability to creat twice the same table

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].